# Java, getting the LinkedList without an object

Tags: java, collections

I am making an implementation for a LinkedListSet that extends LinkedList.
I don't have a LinkedList object in my class, just using the methods from it.
The class has 2 constructors, one without arguments, and one with a Comparator argument.
My problem is when I make an object instantiated with a Comparator.
My solution was to Collections.sort (LinkedList, Comparator) after I add an element in my List, but I don't know how to get my LinkedList without an object, and apply Collections.sort to it.

Comment: "I don't have a LinkedList object in my class,..." yes you do, `this`.

Comment: You get it as mentioned above -- `this`

Comment: Read please Joshua Bloch "Effective java"  Favor composition over inheritance chapter

Comment: Will do, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LinkedList object in your class is the instance of the class itself, the `this`, since because your class extends LinkedList, it ***is*** a LinkedList. Use that as your LinkedList parameter for the sort method:

```
Collections.sort (this, myComparator);
```

Note though as a general rule, you're usually better off using composition and *not* inheritance.

Comment: It would've been much simpler with composition, but I tried something I was not comfortable to do, thank you for the tip :)